# How to make child window with GTK+?

Tags: c, gtk

I have a main window. How to make a child window at fixed position always on top main window which moves, minimizes and maximizes with it?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, it sounds like a rather ... strange idea. Windows are generally managed by the user's chosen window manager; applications should not attempt to have that level of detailed control over the windows.

Comment: On windows, I can create a new window as a child. Everything is ok with it. But on GTK+ I can't take the same behavior.

Comment: Do you mean something like [multiple document interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface)? That's not easily achieved in GTK+, no. You can make child windows, but they won't automatically have the behavior you're after since that is up to the window manager.

Comment: Yes, like MDI. Can you help me with proper events handling? Window move events, window resize events?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that's it very hard, or even impossible. MDI is not a mode that is very well-supported by GTK+ and its assumptions, and *really* not by most non-Windows platforms where you might use GTK+ (such as Linux). [See the last sentence of the first paragraph of that Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface#Comparison_with_single_document_interface), for instance.

Comment: Not the same as MDI. Simply I need popup window inside main window which appears and hides at fixed position on external event (not GTK event).

Answer (score 1):

you can try `gtk_window_set_type_hint(window, GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DIALOG)`

This will make the child window stay on top of the main window.

(Yout may also try `gtk_window_set_transient_for`)